# Fallo al recoger string desde urlopen()

Tags: python, python-3.7

Cuando la función recibe una variable que contiene un string escrito a mano, la función de reemplazar los caracteres funciona, pero cuando recibe la variable desde urlopen(), no funciona. Los dos strings son de tipo str.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*-

import re
from urllib import request
from re import findall, UNICODE
from unidecode import unidecode
import sys

import re
from unicodedata import normalize

response = str(request.urlopen("https://www.amazon.es/Spigen-042CS20927-Carcasa-Protecci%C3%B3n-h%C3%ADbrida/dp/B01M0USRWG/ref=pd_sim_107_5?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B01M0USRWG&pd_rd_r=dee5b20b-0f7b-11e9-b36a-dd935edf15f1&pd_rd_w=fXXgN&pd_rd_wg=Sc7jG&pf_rd_p=cc1fdbc2-a24a-4df6-8bce-e68491d548ae&pf_rd_r=20G8D05BQ984RRGRR8SS&psc=1&refRID=20G8D05BQ984RRGRR8SS").readlines())

Descripcion = re.findall('<title>.*?Amazon', response)
DescripcionA = Descripcion[0].replace('<title>', "")
original = DescripcionA.replace('Amazon', "")


def normalize(s):
    replacements = (
        ("\xc2\xa1", "¡"),
        ("\xc2\xbf", "¿"),
        ("\xc3\x81", "Á"),
        ("\xc3\x89", "É"),
        ("\xc3\x8d", "Í"),
        ("\xc3\x91", "Ñ"),
        ("\xc3\x93", "Ó"),
        ("\xc3\x9a", "Ú"),
        ("\xc3\x9c", "Ü"),
        ("\xc3\xa1", "á"),
        ("\xc3\xa9", "é"),
        ("\xc3\xad", "í"),
        ("\xc3\xb1", "ñ"),
        ("\xc3\xb3", "ó"),
        ("\xc3\xba", "ú"),
        ("\xc3\xbc", "ü")
    )
    for a, b in replacements:
        s = s.replace(a, b).replace(a.upper(), b.upper())
    return s
#Cuando escribo el string a mano, funciona:
text2= "spigen Funda iPhone 7/8, Ultra Hybrid 2 Tecnolog\xc3\xada de amortiguaci\xc3\xb3n de Aire y protecci\xc3\xb3n h\xc3\xadbrida contra ca\xc3\xaddas:"
text2 = normalize(text2)
#Cuando uso la variable que contiene un str No funciona:
text = normalize(original)

print(text)
print(text2)
```

Comment: Intenta pasandolo a string `def normalize(s): s = str(s) ` y luego un `return str(s);`

Comment: Porque no la decodificas. Utiliza`request.urlopen(tu_direccion).read().decode('utf8')`

Comment: @Saelyth Muchas gracias, funcionó =)

Comment: @Bryro eso ya lo había probado, y nada, gracias por responder =)

Comment: Me alegro de que funcione. En ese caso añadiré una respuesta para que puedas aceptarla como válida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las direcciones de request normalmente vienen codificadas, puedes decodificarla utilizando la función decode:

```
request.urlopen(tu_direccion).read().decode('utf8')
```